# QT VC CMake Compiler path

Tags: qt, visual-c++, cmake, qt-creator

I am trying to setup Qt Creator to use the VC2017 compiler. It detects everything automatically but I keep getting a warning for my Kit setup (shown in the tooltip in the screenshot below) that says `CMake configuration has a path to a C/C++ compiler set that does not match the compiler path configured in the tool chain of the kit.`

I changed CMake Configuration to the following values:

```
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:STRING=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe
CMAKE_C_COMPILER:STRING=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH:STRING=%{Qt:QT_INSTALL_PREFIX}
QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE:STRING=%{Qt:qmakeExecutable}
```

But nothing changes. Here's a screenshot:
[image]

Screenshot of the `Compilers` tab:[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Rather than hard-coding the compiler paths in the *CMake Configuration*, use the variables Qt Creator provides for you and then just make sure your kit selects the compilers you want to use from the *Compilers* drop-down box. Your *CMake Configuration* should look something like this:

```
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:STRING=%{Compiler:Executable:Cxx}
CMAKE_C_COMPILER:STRING=%{Compiler:Executable:C}
QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE:STRING=%{Qt:qmakeExecutable}
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH:STRING=%{Qt:QT_INSTALL_PREFIX}
```

The warning is for the kit itself, so it is independent of any build you're trying to use it for. If the warning still persists after setting the *CMake Configuration* to the above, it may just be Qt Creator not recognising the way the compiler executable is specified.

If you've been experimenting a bit along the way and have had build errors, try clearing your build directory and re-running CMake again. The first time you run CMake in an empty build directory, it should log information about the compiler it is trying to use. If it matches what you expect and the CMake run completes successfully, then the warning can be safely ignored (it won't prevent that kit from being used). You can also confirm the compiler being used by looking for the `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` and `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` entries in the `CMakeCache.txt` file at the top of your *build* tree.

Comment: Does the version 15.0 refer to VC2015? Because I only have VC2017 installed and weirdly Qt automatically calls the kit `Qt 5.9.0 MSVC2017 64bit`.

Comment: I removed the hard-coded values and used the default ones, but the problem persists. I am scratching my head on how to point to the VC2017 compiler.

Comment: Oops, sorry, yes my mistake, I misread your compiler setting. Can you also add a screenshot for the Compilers tab which shows the 15.0 compilers selected? Also try blowing away your build directory and re-running CMake again to ensure the right compilers are being picked up by the build. I'll correct my answer once we figure out the problem.

Comment: Your first screenshot shows the _amd64_ compilers selected but you've shown the _amd64_x86_ compilers in the second screenshot. Can you update your second screenshot to show the same compiler as the first?

Comment: Sorry my bad. The only difference is in the `Initialization` path (just a different arg): `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat amd64`

Comment: I've updated my answer, hopefully it clarifies things a little.

Comment: "try clearing your build directory and re-running CMake again" => This helped me!